# Image button imgbtn.click() is only triggering client click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, imagebutton, eventtrigger

I found a problem with my image button. 
I have a client click event bound to the image button and also a server click event. I tried to trigger server side click event from client side using the below code.

```
$("#imagebuttonId").click();

<input name="ImageButton1" title="Go Back" class="backbutton" id="ImageButton1"  type="image" alt="Go Back" src="../Images/go-back.png">
```

But it always trigger the client side click event bound to the image button control. And one thing to mention is while rendering, the image button does not contains onClick="event_call" like other buttons.

It will be very helpful if some one could suggest a solution. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: show definition of client click and image button mark up

Comment: `I tried to trigger server side click event from client side` What do you mean exactly? What type of node is `#imagebuttonId`?

Comment: can you please post your relevant asp code as well.

Comment: @A.Wolff: its an image button. On its client click, I checked a condition and tried to trigger the server click event. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#imagebuttonId").trigger('click');
```

Comment: This is no different to calling `click()`.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: Sure, I will give explanations on future answers.)

Comment: @siva Above code didn't work for me.. trigger still calls client click event :( Could you please suggest?